# get_bucket() gives 'Bad Request' for S3 buckets I didn't create via Boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using Boto to try to get a bucket in Amazon S3, but it returns Bad Request when I use get_bucket() for some of the buckets.  I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug with Boto, since I can get the bucket using get_all_buckets().

```
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
>>> conn = S3Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY)
>>> buckets = conn.get_all_buckets()
>>> buckets
[<Bucket: mysite-backups>]
>>> buckets[0]
<Bucket: mysite-backups>
>>> conn.get_bucket('mysite-backups')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 502, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 549, in head_bucket
    response.status, response.reason, body)
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

>>> conn.create_bucket('mysite_mybucket')
<Bucket: mysite_mybucket>
>>> conn.get_bucket('mysite_mybucket')
<Bucket: mysite_mybucket>
```

This seems to be an issue even if I log in with the same user account as I'm using the access creds for and create it from within the AWS console.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out the issue is because of the region (I was using Frankfurt).  Two ways of dealing with it:

1. Give up on Frankfurt (@andpei points out there are [issues currently reported with it](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2741)) and recreate the bucket in a different region.
2. Specify the region using the 'host' parameter when connecting (thanks @Siddarth):

   ```
   >>> REGION_HOST = 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
   >>> conn = S3Connection(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY, host=REGION_HOST)
   >>> conn.get_bucket('mysite-backups')
   <Bucket: mysite-backups>
   ```

   You can find the relevant region host [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

Answer (score 3):

Use connect to region while dealing with buckets in different regions.

Answer (score 2):

A general and simple solution, that does not involve changing region or setting a specific host, is found at https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2916. After some editing:

> The Frankfurt AWS region (Ireland and CN too, apparently) only support
>   the V4 signature algorithm. (…)
>
> Per the boto documentation, you can either add `[s3] use-sigv4 = True`
>   to your `~/.boto` file or set the `os.environ` list to include
>   S3_USE_SIG_V4: `os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'`.

Comment: Seeing ```boto.s3.connection.HostRequiredError: BotoClientError: When using SigV4, you must specify a 'host' parameter.``` when doing this so looks like host is required.

Comment: Specifying ```host=s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com``` within the **.boto** config file appears to work for boto version **2.49.0**

Answer (score 2):

Add s3 bucket host to boto connection

`conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, host=AWS_HOST)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a combination of EOL and seddonym's answers - first I specified that I'd like to use Sigv4 with the following:

```
os.environ['S3_USE_SIGV4'] = 'True'
```

Then, in connecting to the bucket I had to specify the host, which seemed a bit silly but here goes:

```
s3 = S3Connection('key id', 'access key', host='s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')
```

Note that this is for **Frankfurt only**